# A CSS background with three colors repeated on x axis?

Tags: css, colors, background

Basically I want to imitate the repeat-x trick where you take a 1-pixel strip image and repeat it on the x axis, but using CSS, instead of an image. My header is a grey background, the middle is blue (main content) and the footer is grey. Would there be a way to have it generated in CSS (grey certain pixels high, blue, grey..) AND (tall order if possible) have it be relative to the size of the browser?

Comment: What's wrong with `#header,#footer{background:grey}#content{background:blue}`?

Comment: Sounds like it could be done with gradients, but I think your best course of action would be Data URIs

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for CSS3 Browsers (and IE9 too) using CSS3Pie:
http://css3pie.com/demos/gradient-patterns/

For IE6-8, I don't believe you can do something without images.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? That is a great demo, and it may be what OP is after (although coloring the backgrounds of the separate elements makes much more sense to me).

Comment: Some trolls are here just to downvote. They have mental problems.

Comment: Now THAT is sweet! I think this answers my question.. I should sign up and give that a PLUS.

Comment: And that site in general is really something! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad the link was helpful. Don't forget to mark it as accepted if you considers appropriate for your question.